# How to fix the following code showing this error

Tags: c#

The following code below is concatenating the double variable .

For example first number is `2`
And second is `3` 
It is adding them like this `2+3;`
`23`

```
using System;


public static class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        double num01;
        double num02;

        Console.WriteLine("Add");
        Console.Write("type a number: ");
        num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("type another number: ");
        num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("the result is " + num01 + num02);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the plus operator doesn't add to numbers together when used in a 'string'.  You have effectively written "the result is 1 2"

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("the result is " + (num01 + num02) );`

Comment: So Neil how can I add the code following number please tell me

Comment: If `num01` & `num02` are `double`s why are you using `Convert.ToInt32` ?  Try `Convert.ToDouble` then you can input 1.23 & 4.56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the parentheses to the sum of the number, your code can work

```
        double num01;
        double num02;

        Console.WriteLine("Add");
        Console.Write("type a number: ");
        num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("type another number: ");
        num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("the result is " + (num01 + num02));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

but the best practice without a doubt is:

```
        string.Format
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not added 2 integers together, you have suffixed a string with 2 other numbers.

String concatenation is also 'slow'.  You should use string.Format or string interpolation.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("the result is {0}", num01 + num02) );
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine($"the result is {num01 + num02}");
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"the result is {num01 + num02}");` throw error `unexpected character $`

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The reson is that expression `"the result is " + num01 + num02` is adding, which includes `string`, which makes the whole operation concatentaion, not addition of numbers! If at least one operand of `+` operator is string, it makes it concatenation.

Moreover, then every other operand is converted to string, so your numbers get converted to string and then concatenated.

To prevent that, force order of operation, so addition of your numbers is first, for example (already shown in other answers): `"the result is " + (num01 + num02)`

Now it will first sum two numbers, then concatenate with given `string`.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on: for

```
 "the result is " + num01 + num02
```

we have

1. `"the result is " + num01` which is `"the result is 1"` (adding `double` to `string`)
2. `"the result is 1" + num02` which is `"the result is 12"` (adding `double` to string)

what can you do: put `(..)` and have `"the result is " + (num01 + num02)`:

1. `num01 + num0` which is `3` (adding two `double`s)
2. `"the result is " + 3` which is `"the result is 3"` (adding `double` to `string`)

So you can either put `(...)`

```
 Console.WriteLine("the result is " + (num01 + num02));
```

or (better way) use *string interpolation* and let .net compute the sum for you:

```
 Console.WriteLine($"the result is {num01 + num02}");
```

or formatting:

```
 Console.WriteLine("the result is {0}", num01 + num02);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*It is adding them like this 2+3; 23* "

That is because you are using `+` in a context where it treats `2` and `3` as strings and with strings `+` always perform concatenation, hence the result `23`

> ***What do you need to do to fix things?***

```
Console.WriteLine("the result is " + (num01 + num02) );
```

> ***Why does the above solution works?***

**Short answer:** ***Operator precedence***. Parenthesis has higher precedence and is evaluated first. When that happens num01 and num02 are treated as numbers and addition takes place. And now this sum value is treated like a string in `+` with `"the result is "`